# Laravel 3 Vs Laravel 4 : before filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have in UsersController.php

```
$this->beforeFilter('permission:administration');
```

and in my filers.php ( this is for larval 3 I want to change it to larval 4.2 equivalent)

```
 Route::filter('permission', function($permission)
 {
   if(!Auth::user()->permission($permission)) return App::abort(500);
 });
```

This code is from Laravel 3 and I am trying to make the same thing for Laravel 4.2 I am getting there folioing error :

```
Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Route could not be converted to string
```

How could I fix this , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in routes.php or controller.

In the controller:

```
$this->beforeFilter('permission:administration');
```

in your routes.php file:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'permission:administration'], function() {
   Route::get('my-route', 'UsersController@action');
});
```

or

```
Route::get('my-route', ['before' => 'permission:administration', 'uses' => 'UsersController@action'])
```

To retrieve the "administration" value:

```
Route::filter('permission', function($route, $request, $permission)
 {
   if(!Auth::user()->permission($permission)) return App::abort(500);
 });
```

Comment: I don't think this hanna work for my situation here , if you notice Route:filter() passes a $permission variable that is been passed to the permission() function

Comment: differnet controllers uses this like : I have in ProjectController.php This : $this->beforeFilter('permission:project-modify')